# Get a all specific elements with flag

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, collections, ienumerable

If element contains specific element with flag, get it and add to collection. In my code this means 
get all songs, where genreid == 18 // just for example, number can be any int32//. I'll be glad to see any answers. I used linq to get it, but I see only that number is int32 and nothing else. 
 this is my code : (song list is List)

```
var json = e.Result;
               var jobject = JObject.Parse(json);
               var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
               serializer.Converters.Add(new ResponseDataConverter());
               var songList = jobject["response"].ToObject<SongList>(serializer);
               song.GenreId  = (int)from other in songList.Songs where other.GenreId == 18 select other.GenreId;
```

if it will help you this is my deserialization class : (with overrided methods)

```
 public abstract class ResponseData
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class SongData : ResponseData
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "artist")]
        public string Artist { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
        public string SongName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "url")]
        public string SongUri { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "duration")]
        public int Duration { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "owner_id")]
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "lyrics_id")]
        public int LyricsId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "genre_id")]
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserData : ResponseData
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "photo")]
        public string Photo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name_gen")]
        public string NameGen { get; set; }
    }

    public class SongList
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "count")]
        public int Count { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public List<SongData> Songs { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public List<UserData> Users { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "items")]
        public ResponseData[] Items
        {
            get
            {
                return (Users ?? Enumerable.Empty<UserData>()).Cast<ResponseData>().Concat((Songs ?? Enumerable.Empty<SongData>()).Cast<ResponseData>()).ToArray();
            }
            set
            {
                Songs = (value ?? Enumerable.Empty<ResponseData>()).OfType<SongData>().ToList();
                Users = (value ?? Enumerable.Empty<ResponseData>()).OfType<UserData>().ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ResponseDataConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(ResponseData).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
            Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject item = JObject.Load(reader);
            if (item["name"] != null)
            {
                return item.ToObject<UserData>();
            }
            else
            {
                return item.ToObject<SongData>();
            }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
            object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

I need you help. I spent half part of my day working on that problem. Work with IEnumerable<> collection is hard. So hard. May be I have miss something, but I am young and just study.

Comment: It is not completely clear what you are asking - could you please rephrase your problem, current situation and your expected results in a more detailed and clear way?

Comment: I wanted collection, where will be only elements with genreid == 18. When I got all results from json, I need to sort them to different collections by their genreid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is my understanding of what you're after (correct me if I'm wrong).

You have a list of songs (in this case `songList.Songs`) and you want to get an `IEnumerable<>` collection of all songs with genreid == 18 (or any id).

Just looking at your last line of code (the linq query)...maybe something like...

```
var songsWithId = from sd in songList.Songs
                       where sd.GenreId == 18 
                       select sd;
```

where `songWithId` is an `IEnumerable<SongData>`

In your code you're only selecting the genre Id (`select other.GenreId`), which makes me sort of think I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Before, in previous version of c# you can get list<> instead of IEnumerable<>. Get any element of list is easy. From IEnumerable<> I get int32 instead of genreid number. The main point is separate songs with different genreid to different collections. This is was my way, but it's didn't working. If you have another way solve my problem. Anyway thank you for your answer.

Comment: Hmm...so what you're asking for is a `List<SongData>`...? `var songsWithId = (from sd in songList.Songs where sd.GenreId == 18 select sd).ToList();`

Comment: this is not what I am was looking for, but you answer isn't bad at all. I know how to solve my problem, thanks. I will use you answer and override my json methods.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are explicitly casting the query result to `int`, you need to simply do this:-

```
IEnumerable<int> SongsWithGenreId18  = from other in songList.Songs 
                                       where other.GenreId == 18 
                                       select other.GenreId;
```

Or if you want list directly, simply enumerate it with `ToList` method like this:-

```
List<int> SongsWithGenreId18  = (from other in songList.Songs 
                                where other.GenreId == 18 
                                select other.GenreId).ToList();
```

Now, you can add this List to your collection using [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: if song genreid(for example) == 18, I need to get all songs with this parameter. All other songs is will go to another collection.

Comment: @NikitaGalaganov: Yes this query will filter all songs with GenreId 18 only, another collection as in? Obviously you need to write a separate query for that.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood you correctly, i think this is what you're looking for:

```
var songsWithSpecificGenreId = songList.Where(song => song.GenreId == 18);
```